# BTSync update: 2.0.93 => latest

Tags: raspbian, software-installation

Years ago I installed BTSync from `debian.yeasoft.net` repo.

My `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/btsync.list`:

```
deb http://debian.yeasoft.net/btsync wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://debian.yeasoft.net/btsync wheezy main contrib non-free
```

But the version of BTSync in this repo is **very** old (2.0.93) with limit of 10 free shares.

How can I:

1. Remove current BTSync version
2. Install latest version
3. …and (very important!) not to loose current BTSync settings and current shares?

Comment: Yes! Please, anyone...?

Answer (score 0):

To remove BTsync just type `sudo apt-get remove btsync`

The upgrade is actually pretty easy. If you look at their [download](https://www.getsync.com/platforms/desktop) page, they have an option for ARM. The tar archive contains a README that describes how to start and configure the application.

You may or may not be able to use your existing settings with the new installation. The versions are very different. If you can't, nothing about this process will remove the files. Just re-add the shares as necessary.